# World Space Canvas not showing in Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game and I need a nameplate above the player.

I've got it all working, but it only shows up in the editor and not the game.

I'm sure it's something to do with the camera rendering above it but I don't know how to fix it.

The Canvas is set to the UI layer so that's not the issue.

The Inspector:

[image: Canvas inspector properties]

In-Editor

[image]

In-Game:

[image]

Comment: Without some screens of your scene it will be very hard if not impossible to know

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your inspector with the Canvas selected?

Comment: Ok I've added the image

Comment: You don't need to put Unity or C# in the title of your questions. This is what the tag is used for. I am only saying this because you've been doing it for a long time now. Also you can actually accept answers from your old questions if they solved your problem you.

Comment: 1) I didn't know that so ty for letting me know
2) On my old posts it wouldn't let me accept the answers but I've been doing that recently.

Comment: Still not enough information to solve your problem. If your canvas is in worldspace, your UI elements still need to be within it's bounds and still follow the normal rules of occlusion.

Comment: I've added two screenshots of the issue. I'll try and add some more info in a bit

Answer (score 3):

When you change the Canvas's Camera mode from Overlay to World, it resets its `RectTranform` *z*, *y*, *z* position value.

You have to set the x and y axis to *0*. After that you must move the z axis forward so that the `Canvas` will be positioned in front of the Camera. It is likely behind the camera. So if the camera's z-axis pos is about *-10*, you have to move the canvas z-axis forward to about 460.The distance to move it actually depends on the distance of the Camera's z-axis.

Remember that the Canvas is now in **world space** which means that it can be in front of other objects, back of them or in the middle of any them. You have to continue to modify the z-axis until you get the right position where nothing is blocking it. The easiest way to do this is to click the *Pos-Z* axis then drag it with the mouse as demonstrated below..

[image]